# What is the slowest converging sequence ever used in a serious mathematical proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Like for example $x^{-\frac{1}{G}}$ where $G$ is Graham's number.  Of course this is not a serious one, just an example.  I have no idea if this one was ever used by any mathematician in a proof.  But I'm sure some insane sequence like this one was used in some proof somewhere at some point.

As a side exercise, can you construct one that grows slower the one I invented?

Comment: What about $x^{-1/(2G)}$ ? Or $1/\log(x)$? (as $x \rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: Define $G'$ to be the number constructed the same way Graham's number is constructed but using $G$'s instead of $3$'s.  Then we have $x^{-\frac{1}{G'}}$.  Or, to expand on Michael's other example, something like $\frac{1}{ln(e^n + ln(e^{n-1} + ln( ...(e+ln(x) ... ))}$

Comment: I meant used in an actual mathematical proof.

Comment: I am sure $1/\log(x)$ has been used lots.

Comment: Proofs in analytic number theory often involve $\log\log n$, even $\log\log\log n$, occasionally $\log\log\log\log n$. Slow growing, reciprocals are slow converging.

Comment: For very large $x, \frac 1{\log x} \gt x^{-\frac 1G}$, so even $\frac 1{\log x}$ converges more slowly.

Answer (score 2):

You may be particularly interested in the iterated logarithm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

On that page it states that the slowest growing function in complexity theory is the inverse Ackerman function.